# validation error on prettyPhoto's rel attribute

Tags: html

It is looks like W3C's validator return a validation error on prettyPhoto's rel attribute for HTML5 pages. How do I solve this error?

***Bad value prettyPhoto[gallery1] for attribute rel on element a: Keyword prettyphoto[gallery1] is not registered.***

Many thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `rel` attribute with non-proposed (thus not allowed) values not valid for HTML5 markup. Value `prettyPhoto` is not in the list of proposed values. So you may face the difficulties with getting your web-page with image gallery passing validation.

**A Possible Solution:**

1. Open `jquery.prettyPhoto.js` (presumably non-minified one) and perform find & replace function of your text-editor: 
   replace all occurrences of `attr('rel')` with `attr('data-gal')`.
2. In your gallery code use:
   `data-gal="prettyPhoto[galname]"`
   instead of:
   `rel="prettyPhoto[galname]"`
3. Initialize your prettyPhoto with:

   `jQuery("a[data-gal^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();`

   And you are on the right way for getting your code valid!

**You can also read this [article](http://forums.no-margin-for-errors.com/discussion/1741/achieve-clean-validation-for-html5/p1) with this possible solution.**

Comment: Same for me. In the end it is even easier than that. Change hook: 'rel' into whatever you need. Thanks to all posters here! Awesome help (as usual)!!!

Answer (score 9):

You can use the (undocumented) `hook` setting as mentioned in the comments [here](http://forums.no-margin-for-errors.com/discussion/comment/12039#Comment_12039).

Specify your links like this: `<a href="img.jpg" data-gal="prettyPhoto[gal]"></a>` and use `$("a[data-gal^='prettyPhoto'").prettyPhoto({hook: 'data-gal'});` to initialize prettyPhoto.

Answer (score 0):

You can also fix it by updating the settings to use the class hook:

```
s = jQuery.extend({
        ...
        hook: "rel",
        animation_speed: "fast",
        ajaxcallback: function() {},
        slideshow: 5e3,
        autoplay_slideshow: false,
        opacity: .8,
        ...
```

to:

```
s = jQuery.extend({
        ...
        hook: "class",
        ...
```