# prettyPhoto gallery without rel attribute

Tags: prettyphoto

I'm using prettyPhoto (http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/)

According to documentation it's being triggered by:

```
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
```

However, I'm using just this (rel attribute is not valid according to W3C and it's not needed):

```
$(".photo a").prettyPhoto();
```

But I need to make my photos as a gallery, according to documentation it's made by using this:

```
<a href="images/1.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]"><img src="images/1b.jpg" /></a>
```

(rel tag has gallery name between `[` `]`)

---

Is there any way how to define gallery without rel tag?

Comment: I answered your question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15765003/1865857). I hope it's ok to post it here as just a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution via the comment above: [validation error on prettyPhoto's rel attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297854/validation-error-on-prettyphotos-rel-attribute/15765003#15765003)

Specify your links like this: `<a href="img.jpg" data-gal="prettyPhoto[gal]"></a>` and use `$("a[data-gal^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({hook: 'data-gal'});` to initialize prettyPhoto.