# prettyphoto lightbox html5 validation error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, prettyphoto

I am using prettyphoto jQuery lightbox plugin. i have following html line

```
<a href="images/img1.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="heading" /></a>
```

and when I try validate the html code it gives me following error message

> Bad value prettyPhoto for attribute rel on element a: The string prettyphoto is not a registered keyword or absolute URL.

What should I do to correct this. Since `rel="prettyPhoto"` is necessary for the plugin to work properly I don't understand how to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the rel attribute with jQuery

```
$('a').attr('rel', 'prettyPhoto');
```

But I dont know if validator checks the original HTML or also checks the final HTML.

Comment: Thanks
and i found another way of doing it 

 i used class="prettyPhoto" instead of rel="prettyPhoto" and initialized using the class. 

Thank you again for the answer.

Comment: Well, you can use any selector you want, theoretically. I thought there must be a rel attribute. Anyways, nice to hear ;)

Comment: @sam: Navigation (prev / next) might not be working using your approach. You might want to have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297854/validation-error-on-prettyphotos-rel-attribute